# How to compile geometry layout twice on one page?

Tags: geometry

I'm designing an invitation card with the geometry package. My content fits twice on an A4 sheet, so I'd like to save half the paper. How can have each page content twice per page?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    a4paper,
    top=15mm,
    bottom=15mm,
    left=13.5mm,
    right=13.5mm,
    layoutsize=138mm,
    % offsets without double content per page
    layouthoffset=36mm,
    layoutvoffset=79.5mm,
    showcrop
}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{tgchorus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \centering

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Velit sed morbi.

    \vfill

    Orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis \\
    \vspace{5mm}
    {\fontsize{24pt}{32pt}\selectfont 14. November 2015}

    \vfill

    Bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. \\
    Hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue.

    \vfill

    - ac tincidunt vitae semper quis -

    \clearpage

    Quisque in ornare est, euismod iaculis metus. Aenean consectetur commodo eros, ac efficitur massa.

    \vfill

    In in mattis tellus. Curabitur ac leo a eros accumsan lacinia. Phasellus pulvinar eget metus non mollis. Maecenas non hendrerit risus.

    \vfill

    Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec non varius erat. Fusce laoreet enim laoreet, molestie massa at, lacinia erat.

    \vfill

    Pellentesque maximus ipsum a ultrices imperdiet. Donec volutpat odio id lacinia auctor. Ut sit amet justo sed justo semper consequat nec ac tortor.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `geometry` settings is always valid for whole page. If you like change this only on part of page, than look for environment `\adjustwidth` from the `changepage` package: `\begin{adjustwidth}{<leftmargin>}{<rightmargin>}`

Comment: Maybe you can adjust your printer/printing software to print multiple pages on one sheet.

Comment: Not clear what you want exactly,  but should be some like `\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}` or otherwise   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry} (But without using \clearpage . However, change the printer options  is easier ...

Comment: I discarded doing this via the printer because I was afraid of scaling. I like your suggestions and I will try to set my page up as A5 and then print two per A4 paper. There shouldn't be any scaling then... Thanks!

Comment: There are several ways to print two "pages" on one sheet of paper.  Pdfpages and flowfram come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Basically define a macro that holds the invitation, then call the macro twice on the page. Not an MWE but to give you the idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
% other preamble stuff
\newcommand{\invite}{The code for the invitation.}
\begin{document}

\invite
\vfill % some space between the invitations 
\invite
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can I use a `geometry` from the geometry package in the `\invite` macro? The layoutsize and -offsets have to match exactly.

Comment: @oschlueter I have misunderstood your question as I had not realised that your invitation was two--sided. All I can suggest is `\inviteA` and `\inviteB` for first and second pages, then `inviteA \vfill \inviteA \clearpage \inviteB \vfill \inviteB`.